# ElasticSearch: Need a bool string with AND clauses connected by OR

Tags: elasticsearch

I have been trying to figure out how to make the following boolean structure in elasticsearch, to no avail:

(name = "Ben" AND car = "Honda") OR (name = "James" AND (car = "Ford" OR car = "Toyota"))

Comment: you're missing some parenthesis at the end, how the the last OR combine with the last AND?

Comment: this are two combination i can think of from your requirement. can you please confirm which one you are looking for: First => `(name = "Ben" AND car = "Honda") OR (name = "James" AND (car = "Ford" OR car = "Toyota"))` Second => `(name = "Ben" AND car = "Honda") OR ((name = "James" AND car = "Ford") OR car = "Toyota")` based on your confirmation i will provide ES query.

Comment: Hi Sagar - thank you! The first is the correct one.

Comment: @SagarPatel just wanted to follow up - I would greatly appreciate any help/support. thanks again.

Comment: Please check if below my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) type of the query with same expression as it support `OR` and `AND` operator.

```
POST carindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "(name:Ben AND car:Honda) OR (name:James AND (car:Ford OR car:Toyota))"
    }
  }
}
```

Below is boolean query for your condition:

```
POST carindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "name": {
                    "value": "Ben"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "car": {
                    "value": "Honda"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "name": {
                    "value": "James"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "terms": {
                  "car": [
                    "Ford",
                    "Toyota"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

PS: I have consider `name` and `car` field as `keyword` type of field in above query. If you have defined field as multi type of field then you may need to use like `name.keyword` and `car.keyword`.